# How to prevent the auto creation of the "Desktop" folder?

Tags: arch-linux, firefox, gtk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which application should I blame for compulsively creating a directory again and again?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21316/which-application-should-i-blame-for-compulsively-creating-a-directory-again-and)

When I upload files via Firefox, the `Open File` dialog appears and the `Desktop` folder is automatically created. I am using Arch Linux with Xmonad and quite frankly I don't need a `Desktop` folder inside my `home` folder.

How do I stop this from happening in the future (i.e. disable the auto creation of the `Desktop` folder)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do this by creating or editing a file called `user-dirs.dirs` in `~/.config`. Mine has the following:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="/srv/documents/"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/downloads/"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="/srv/music/"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="/srv/pictures/"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME"
```

Firefox follows whatever you have for `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR`.

Comment: Simply run: `xdg-user-dirs-update --set DESKTOP ~`