# How to trace that what had "chmod 640"'ed the "/etc/passwd" file?

Tags: aix

On AIX 6100-05-02-1034, something is frequently changing the permissions of the `/etc/passwd` file to 640. That's bad...

How could I trace that what is chmoding the file? There is no `history 1000 | fgrep -i chmod`, I think a process is chmoding the file, but which one? `dtrace` can do this? it's not on AIX

Comment: Shouldn't you be grepping for `chmod`, not `chown`?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6068/is-it-possible-to-find-out-what-program-or-script-created-a-given-file

Comment: :D no. CHMOD is the right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dtrace would be nice but it's not ported on AIX.

You should be able to trace what is chmoding the file with auditing: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-audit/

Comment: I can see S_PASSWD_READ and S_PASSWD_WRITE, but what should I set to trace the chown-ing? so are there any "S_PERMISSION"? :D - ty!

Comment: I have no AIX system to check but I guess FILE_Mode should be a good clue.

Answer (score 0):

At first I'd open a problem record with IBM as that sounds like broken code and  should be fixed. I personally only had similar issues with /etc/resolv.conf also not readable by others, and when it belongs to root:system that might be a problem.

The pointer to audit subsystem is correct, although the famous developerworks URL-randomizer struck, and the above link is not working anymore. Check e.g. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.security/monitor_file_access_realtime.htm or the archived page: https://web.archive.org/web/20080328022606/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-audit/

For the event selection, you should try with FILE_Write and maybe in addition FILE_Mode, FILE_Privilege and/or FILE_Acl