# How to trace file locks (per directory)

Tags: files, lock, trace

I'm quite new to Linux and I have not really a clue on how to do this.

I've got a directory and I'd like to monitor (output to shell) when a file inside that directory get's a file lock and when it is released.

It would be okay to know as well other things, like when a file is created and similar, but I'm mainly interested about the locks.

I don't need to know which process does the lock, it's more about the order in which this happens.

I'm pretty sure some tool for this exists (I already installed `dtrace` but after `--help` I decided to ask a question here).

Any pointers warm-heartedly appreciated. I'm running a fedora 14 box if that matters.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6068/is-it-possible-to-find-out-what-program-or-script-created-a-given-file/6080#6080

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: The suggestion was really good, but I totally failed with both approaches. But that's my fault (not able to get LoggedFS to build and auditctl is installed but I can't get it log because of some errors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't checked that you will get what you want with it, but the first thing I'd try is the [audit subsystem](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/). Make sure that the `auditd` daemon is started, then use [`auditctl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/auditctl.8.html) to configure what you want to log. For ordinary filesystem accesses, you would do

```
auditctl -w /path/to/directory
auditctl -a exit,always -S fnctl -S open -S flock -F dir=/path/to/directory
```

The `-S` option can be used to restrict the logging to specific syscalls. The logs appear in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` on Debian, and probably on Fedora as well.

If you do know which process(es) may lock the file, then consider running `strace` on these processes (and only looking at the file-related system calls, or further restricting to specific syscalls).

```
strace -s9999 -o foo.strace -e file foo
```

Comment: `auditctl -a exit,always -w /path/to/directory` -> Error: `watch option can't be given with a syscall`, I already learned that `exit` is related to syscall from the manpage. But it didn't help me ;). About strace, I have not tried, as I test a process I launch and it exists (like PHP CGI, but in CLI), is there an option to make strace start the command like with dbg? I think I should be able to dig through the strace output, should be interesting anyway.

Comment: just installed `strace`, I already see I can add the command behind, will try with it --- **edit:** this is cool!

Comment: @hakre Oops, `-w` implicitly sets `-a`. Fixed. In the forme I've given, strace starts the command `foo`. To attach to a running process, use `strace -p1234` where 1234 is the pid.

Comment: when I remove `-S fnctl,open` I get `auditctl` to run and can see the log (same location as on debian). If I don't remove it, I get: `Syscall name unknown: fnctl,open`. I think `fnctl` is especially interesting regarding the file-locks. - *edit* just seeing, it's probably `fcntl`. However the error message is still the same, maybe the `,` is not correct or something, will check the manpage. `strace` does not show any log information.

Comment: I got this to run now: `auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S fcntl -S open -F dir=/path/to/dir`, but it looks like that I still get no locking info (at least not the one I'm looking for, it's a PHP script, I might need to look into PHP sources if I'm looking in the wrong place). Thanks for your help so far, this is the second time!

Comment: @hakre There are several system calls that can implement locks. Add at least `flock` to your list. Strace outputs to a file (`foo.strace` in my example); you should start with it, so you can see what syscall your program uses to implement locks.

Comment: I first looked into `foo.strace`, but I could not see any locking calls. About the files in question it's only `open()` and `unlink()`. I might want to check the command line parameters though. I've just seen that not using `-e file` logs everything (it's only a small script, so was still ok) and there I have `flock()`'s inside.

Comment: Okay, I think I now understood a bit more. I need to specify the actual system calls, in my case, those are: `open,close,flock,fcntl,fstat,pwrite,write,read`. `strace` is really cool tool to get a view on what's going on. Thanks again for your help.