# How can I log who creates a directory?

Tags: linux, directory, logs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to find out what program or script created a given file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6068/is-it-possible-to-find-out-what-program-or-script-created-a-given-file)

Is it possible to log which process/user/IP created a directory? I only found out that the `syslog.conf` is responsible for that. But how can I manage my goal?