# find top 10 latest modified files

Tags: files, disk-usage

How do I get the last 10 files that were modified on my system. I have a system where its disk usage is maxed out I am not sure which files is increasing rapidly.

I have a mysql instance stored on a separate mounted device and I just created a softlink unto my /var/lib directory on my root device. I know symlinks does not affect disk usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find`, `stat`, `sort`, and `tail` to do that.

`find . -exec stat --format="%X" + | sort -n | tail -n 10`

However, you might consider using `watch` and `du`. `watch` will run a command periodically (every 2sec by default). And `du` shows disk usage. This command will show you the disk usage of every file and folder in the current directory, and the output will continuously be refreshed.

```
watch "du -s *"
```

You can start at root and see which folder is increasing the quickest, then progress down the folder hierarchy until you find the culprit(s).

If you're in a folder that has too many files to see on the screen at once, you can limit it by segregating the files like `du -s [a-h]*`. Also, this won't show hidden files; for that you need `.*` or `.[a-h]*`, etc.

Comment: Hi when I run your first command I get this. find: missing argument to `-exec'

Answer (score 1):

You could put together a `find`+`sort`+... etc. command to do what you ask quite literally. But to achieve the goal of finding the top-disk-usage program, better use **[iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/)**.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try live monitoring with either [LoggedFS](http://loggedfs.sourceforge.net/) or Linux's [audit subsystem](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/) (or your unix variant's equivalent feature). See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6068/is-it-possible-to-find-out-what-program-or-script-created-a-given-file/6080#6080) for more information. Note that if a lot of programs use this filesystem, this will produce a lot of logs. Make sure that you aren't logging to the watched filesystem. With the audit subsystem, this rule should do the trick.

```
auditctl -a exit,always -F dir=/mount/point -S write
```