# How do I track all the most recent file changes on my UNIX system?

Tags: files

Say, either for a Debian system or a Red Hat one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [find top 10 latest modified files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22772/find-top-10-latest-modified-files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For real time monitoring you can use [inotify-tools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/inotify-tools/). It can either wait until a certain event occurs, or to run endlessly and report events as they occur. After installing, see `man inotifywait` for details.

The [Debian package](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/inotify-tools) has the same name, the Red Hat package too.

Answer (score 2):

It won't monitor for new changes (unless you make a cron script out of it), but check out `find`'s `-cmin/-cnewer/-ctime` options.

Answer (score 1):

The open source version of tripwire will do that.  See http://sourceforge.net/projects/tripwire/ for more info.  You may have to compile it for your particular OS, or maybe there's a package, but it can be set to provide a daily report of files changed.