# Monitor file system

Tags: filesystems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to find out what program or script created a given file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6068/is-it-possible-to-find-out-what-program-or-script-created-a-given-file)

How do I monitor the file system for specific purposes?

For example, I read that `shutdown` (when called with a delay) creates the file `/etc/nologin` to prevent `login` from accepting new users.

If I were to verify this, is there a tool I could ask, and then it would say, "That's right, between X and Y there was such a file and it was accessed 4 times" - ?

Comment: You might get some ideas by searching this site for `inotify` or the `auditd` system.

Answer (score 3):

On systems that support it (Solaris, Free/NetBSD, Mac OS/X, Oracle Linux), a simple [dtrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace) script would be a useful tool for this task.

Comment: I'm on Debian. But thumbs up anyway because those are very common systems.