# Supervise File Operations

Tags: files, logs

I want to find out what file operations (failed and successful) where performed in the last hour on my system. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't see a history of file operations unless you have monitored and logged them. There are some ways to do that, like the ptrace() system call or the strace command line utility, or perhaps even [DTrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace), but if you didn't log the actions, you'll only have the file time stamps to work with.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of information is not logged by default (that would be a lot of information)!

If you want to see what a particular process is doing, run it under [`strace`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) (that's the Linux utility, other Unix variants have similar utilities such as [`truss`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truss_(Unix)), `dtrace`, etc.). By default `strace` logs all the system calls. You can control what kind of information `strace` displays; for example the option `-efile` restricts the logging to system calls that access files.

```
strace -o myprogram.log -efile myprogram --option
```

If you want to log accesses to all files in a particular hierarchy, you can use [LoggedFS](http://loggedfs.sourceforge.net/). See [Is it possible to find out what program or script created a given file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6068/is-it-possible-to-find-out-what-program-or-script-created-a-given-file/6080#6080) for a usage example. Don't log the directory where the logs are being written!

A more pervasive logging mechanism is Linux's [audit subsystem](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/). It runs as root. See [Is it possible to find out what program or script created a given file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6068/is-it-possible-to-find-out-what-program-or-script-created-a-given-file/6080#6080) for configuration instructions and a usage example. Don't log the directory where the logs are being written!