# CIFS debugging - not enough information

Tags: rhel, debugging, cifs

I am using RedHat RHEL 6. The goal is to identify whether an application running on the local server is setting 'HIDDEN' file attribute on the remote CIFS share.

I have first enabled the logging in syslog config:

> kern.*;*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none               /var/log/messages
>
> *.debug               /var/log/cifs-log

Then, I have set the logging level to 9:

> echo 7 > /proc/fs/cifs/cifsFYI
>
> echo 1 > /proc/fs/cifs/traceSMB

As a result, all I get for the attempt of one of the local applications to write file attributes is the following:

> Oct 19 17:09:53 linux-server kernel: fs/cifs/inode.c: Update
> attributes: \FileShare\Documents\filename.xml inode 0xffff8800465a3af0
> count 1 dentry: 0xffff8804069b78c0 d_time 13784446293 jiffies
> 13978389210

How do I find out what attributes were set exactly? Was it just the time and jiffytime that were updated?

Comment: Somewhat related: [*Is it possible to find out what program or script created a given file?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6068/is-it-possible-to-find-out-what-program-or-script-created-a-given-file) The answers there could be adapted for monitoring changes in file attributes.

Comment: Slightly different, because their scenario is "This is my *nix filesystem, and I want to know what's going on here.", while my scenario is "This is my pool of applications, and I want to know what they do on the REMOTE server". But thank you for the link - useful info!