# How can you figure out which program/process is creating a file?

Tags: linux, files, process

Suppose there's a file that keeps appearing in my home directory automatically even after I delete it. Knowing nothing more about it, is there a way to figure how what keeps putting that file there? Is there a way to track down the program/process that creates it?

Comment: Seems to me like you could use https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6068/117549 ...?

Comment: or also [auditd](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/chap-system_auditing) with the right [configuration](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-defining_audit_rules_and_controls#sec-Defining_Audit_Rules_with_auditctl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `sysdig`: an open-source system monitoring application.  Using it, you can monitor for activity on a file by name. Suppose that you wanted to see what process was creating a file named `/tmp/example.txt`:

```
# sysdig fd.name=/tmp/example.txt
567335 16:18:39.654437223 0 touch (5470) < openat fd=3(<f>/tmp/example.txt) dirfd=-100(AT_FDCWD) name=/tmp/example.txt flags=70(O_NONBLOCK|O_CREAT|O_WRONLY) mode=0666
567336 16:18:39.654438248 0 touch (5470) > dup fd=3(<f>/tmp/example.txt)
567337 16:18:39.654438592 0 touch (5470) < dup res=0(<f>/tmp/example.txt)
567338 16:18:39.654439629 0 touch (5470) > close fd=3(<f>/tmp/example.txt)
567339 16:18:39.654439764 0 touch (5470) < close res=0
567342 16:18:39.654441958 0 touch (5470) > close fd=0(<f>/tmp/example.txt)
567343 16:18:39.654442111 0 touch (5470) < close res=0
```

From that output, you can see that a process named `touch` with pid 5470 opened the file.

If you want more information, you could run in "capture mode" where a system call trace is collected:

```
# sysdig -w /tmp/dumpfile.scap
```

Then wait for the file to be created, then stop `sysdig` and run:

```
# csysdig -r /tmp/dumpfile.scap
```

That'll let you explore everything that happened.  You can press `<F2>` and select `Files`, the press `<F4>` to search for the filename, then press `<F6>` to "dig" (which will show you output similar to the command above).  With that, you can then use the same approach to find information about the process that actually created the file.

There's a GUI version of `csysdig` called `sysdig-inspect`, if that's more your cup of tea.

Comment: This is a pretty nice tool! And I found out the cause! :) You should write this up as an answer to [this question too](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6068/74616).